# javascript google script appendRow fails Service Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Google Apps Script that has been running for 3 months and starting a few weeks ago I'm getting a "Service Error" on the Appendrow function which I've bolded below.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function updateACOPS2(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".....") 
  var sheetSubmission = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet8");
  var dataSubmission = sheetSubmission.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastColSubmission = sheetSubmission.getLastColumn();
  var ssActive = SpreadsheetApp.openById("....")
  var sheetActive = ssActive.getSheetByName("AcopsAll");
  var sheetMain = ssActive.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dataActive = sheetActive.getDataRange().getValues();
  var lastrow = sheetActive.getLastRow(); 

  for(var i = 1; i < dataSubmission.length && dataSubmission[i][2] != ""; i++){

    var currentIDSubmission = dataSubmission[i][2] + dataSubmission[i][3];
    var checkGotMatch = false;
    var toCopyRow = sheetSubmission.getRange(i+1,1,1,71);   
// copy entire row for new record
    Logger.log(currentIDSubmission);

  // if there is a matching record flag as matched

    for(var j = 1; j<dataActive.length; j++){

      var currentIDActive = dataActive[j][2] + dataActive[j][3];
      var currentIDSub = dataSubmission[i][2];

      if(currentIDSub != '' && currentIDSubmission == currentIDActive){  

        checkGotMatch = true;
        Logger.log(currentIDActive);

        break;

      }

    }

    // if it is a new record Append entire row

    if(currentIDSub != '' && checkGotMatch == false){

      **sheetMain.appendRow(toCopyRow.getValues()[0]);**

    }      
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  ss.toast("ACOPS Active has been updated.", "Complete");
}
```

Comment: If it worked before and it does not work now, you may be exceeding some usage limit. If this is a timed trigger, try increasing the interval between runs.

Answer (score -1):

In appendRow you need to pass an array so update your appendRow and try

```
sheetMain.appendRow([toCopyRow.getValues()[0]])
```

Comment: `toCopyRow.getValues()[0]` is an array, because `getValues` returns a 2D array. So the syntax is right in the OP, and is wrong in this answer.